# Advice on Putting Together a Segmented Image

Tags: android

I need to put together a complete image, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Or5f.jpg). Each piece of the segmented tree is an individual image, but I am unsure about how I should put the pieces together efficiently with spacing in between. I've thought about stacking the images on top of each other one at a time within a canvas, but I have my doubts as to whether this is the approach that I should take. Is there a different type of container I should use or a better method of accomplishing the same task?

**EDIT**: just to clarify, I need to assemble the image programmatically, beginning with the base segment and eventually ending with the top segment.

Comment: Use a canvas and draw the segments onto it.  Don't over-complicate what is a simple task.

Comment: You can use a relativeLayout . and Can have 1imageview set to bottom of another image view with leftMargin .

Answer (score 0):

If you use a program like Gimp, you can added each image as a layer, then move the layers around correctly.  I'm not quite sure how you want to represent the space between the segments, transparent?

Any way after you have your image assembled the way you want you can either merge the layers or save it to a format that will flatten out your images.

I'm not sure if you want your image to be able to stretch at all or not.  If so, you can save it as a .png file and then use draw9patch or equivalent to add in stretching segments.  Also I'm not sure if you have to support multiple drawable sizes, if so I have a free Android app, DP Image Calculator on Google Play that might help.  Just remember start with the highest resolution and work you way down to the smallest.

Hope this helps.  If you have more question let me know.  Have a great day.